# Dictionary structure with data from multiple lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I would like to ask for a small guideline regarding the following code structure.

For example, suppose I have the following lists already created and filled with data:

```
movie_name
movie_description
movie_poster
movie_year
movie_duration
```

Is this possible to make a dictionary with the following structure with data taken from the lists:

```
    { movie_name : [
                    {description : movie_description},
                    {poster : movie_poster},
                    {year : movie_year},
                    {duration : movie_duration}
                   ]
    }
```

Thank you.

Comment: what is `movie_name` and others, pure strings? a lists? if lists - what is their content? The input data is unclear

Comment: Those are list of strings

Comment: you mean this `l = ['movie_name','movie_description',movie_poster' ...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the indices of these lists align you can just `zip` them together to get tuples containing these values. You could then with a simple dictionary comprehension turn it in the datastructure you want.

```
res = {
    name: {
        'description': description,
        'poster': poster,
        'year': year,
        'duration': duration
    }
    for name, description, poster, year, duration in zip(
        movie_name,
        movie_description,
        movie_poster,
        movie_year,
        movie_duration
    )
}
```

Comment: This is the solution, thank you. Can you please elaborate more on the solution explanation.